# grouped users, consecutive value matched on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
student_id | date       | exam_id | value
-----------------------------------------
10000      | 2015-01-01 | 1234232 | 'PASSED'
10000      | 2015-01-02 | 3123323 | 'PASSED'
10000      | 2015-01-03 | 4012031 | 'PASSED'
10000      | 2015-01-04 | 5012031 | 'PASSED'
10000      | 2015-01-05 | 7012031 | 'PASSED'
10000      | 2015-01-06 | 6012031 | 'FAILED'
20000      | 2015-01-01 | 1234232 | 'PASSED'
20000      | 2015-01-02 | 3123323 | 'PASSED'
20000      | 2015-01-03 | 4012031 | 'PASSED'
20000      | 2015-01-04 | 5012031 | 'FAILED'
20000      | 2015-01-05 | 7012031 | 'PASSED'
20000      | 2015-01-06 | 6012031 | 'FAILED'
20000      | 2015-01-07 | 9012031 | 'PASSED'
30000      | 2015-01-01 | 1234232 | 'FAILED'
30000      | 2015-01-02 | 3123323 | 'PASSED'
30000      | 2015-01-03 | 4012031 | 'PASSED'
30000      | 2015-01-04 | 5012031 | 'PASSED'
30000      | 2015-01-05 | 7012031 | 'PASSED'
30000      | 2015-01-06 | 6012031 | 'PASSED'
30000      | 2015-01-07 | 6012031 | 'FAILED'
```

I would like to extract each different student (id) that passed 5 or more exams consecutively. The desired output would look like this:

```
student_id 
----------
10000
30000
```

The student with id 2000 should be excluded because even if he passed 5 exams, he didn't passed 5 consecutive exams.

That's pretty straightforward with scripting, but I was wondering if there's also a MySQL solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, probably the easiest way to do this is using variables:

```
select distinct student_id
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@sp = concat(student_id, ':', value), @rn + 1,
                        if(@sp := concat(student_id, ':', value), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @sp := '') vars
      order by student_id, date
     ) t
where rn = 5 and value = 'passed'
```

The subquery enumerates the rows for each student by date and value.  The outer query selects the distinct students where the enumerated value is 5 and the value is "passed".

Comment: I've tried to run the query on this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8b37/2/0 but I'm getting no result. It seems that it's not enumerating each row correctly, as the value is always 1 (I verified running the query with rn=1 and it returns all students)

Comment: @conan . . . There was a typo in the second line, using `@s` instead of `@sp`.  Here is a working SQL Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8b37/8.